# SharedPreferences for general app preferences and user session identificators

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to save two kinds of preference information.

1) General app preferences like results per page, `sessionTime`, etc. which are accessible only once you're logged in.

2) A session identifier like the users name and surname. One can see the name on every activity/page so as to know the the session is ok.

Is it ok for me to use `sharedPreferences` with 2 separate string identifiers. One for general settings and another for session info and manage the usage of these setting through my global application class or is my approach totally wrong?

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/2012/05/android-shared-preferences.html

Comment: I think if you want to have information separatelly use 2 shared preferences. Just use different names in getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME, 0);

Comment: yes @vandzi thats what i trying to do. mPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE); and sPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CurrentUser", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);. ok its good to know im on the wright road. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design Android does not differ between application/user preferences. Don't bother creating 2 different preference files, just use `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(yourContext)` everywhere

Comment: and then depending on which variable i want, i just call that? isn't it though not very secure?

Comment: Yes, you call like mPrefs.getString(yourprefname, "defaultString") where mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(yourContext)

It's no more and no less secure than having several preferences files.

Comment: Security is same. Preferences in private mode are visible only for application.